# Lua remove first directory from path

Tags: lua

How can I remove the first directory from path string (if exists)?

I tried several times with `gsub` and `string.match` but I cannot get this working.

Inputs:

```
/
/tmp/file.txt
/tmp/folder/file2.txt
/tmp/folder/.../file3.txt
```

---

Outputs:

```
/
/file.txt
/folder/file2.txt
/folder/.../file3.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```lua
local paths = {
    '/',
    '/tmp/file.txt',
    '/tmp/folder/file2.txt',
    '/tmp/folder/.../file3.txt'
}

for _, path in ipairs (paths) do
    local trimmed = path:gsub ('^/[^/]+', '')
    print (trimmed)
end
```

The necessary regular expression is `^/[^/]+`. It is anchored to the beginning of the string and requires at least one non-slash character after, so that `/` does not match.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua

dirsep = package .config :sub( 1, 1 )
cwd = '/tmp/folder/file2.txt'
delimeter = { cwd :find( dirsep, 2 ) }
subdir = cwd :sub( delimeter [1] or 1 )

print( subdir )
```

/folder/file2.txt

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: I've used variable names that explain what's going on.  dirsep is the directory separator.  cwd is the current working directory.  delimeter literally finds the delimiter.  subdir IS the subdir.  How is this hard to follow?

Comment: Well-named variables are not an explanation of what your code does, and how and why it works.